# Will auto layout scaling always produce the same result no matter the resolution?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, image-resizing

Is there a way to have each preview/simulator match the look of the storyboard, look for look, regarding the same location and aspect ratio no matter the screen size? In other words, in my storyboard I have the look I am looking for. What properties/details would I have to add to have the storyboard be replicated the same despite the different iPhone resolutions? The iPhone 5.5" looks incredibly close to my desired results while the 4" cuts some of my buttons off? What am I missing or what should I add?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what Auto Layout is for. Your Storyboard is a fixed size whereas there are many different device screen sizes. That's why you use Auto Layout to position view relative to one another so that no matter the device, the layout looks right. In your case, your content will probably need to scroll to fit in all device screen sizes.

Comment: Let me ask this then.  Assuming the storyboard on the left, would I be able to add properties to the auto layout so that 4" iPhone would appear identical?  As in font would be smaller and have a smaller footprint in the middle of the screen?  Regardless, thank you for your first answer haha.

Comment: You would add constraints, and you would need to turn on font shrinking for the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The reason behind this is vector image generation during stretch in or out. If you convert it into raster images. Expected result is not guaranteed.